# Wordle Art Challenge

Tags: wordplay, anagram

Design [eight-bit-style](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=8%20bit%20art) glyphs in 6x5 pixels with three colors that can be used as a secondary challenge in [Wordle](https://www.powerlanguage.co.uk/wordle/).

Answers should be appropriate glyphs containing rows that are possible to generate in real Wordle play and are (at least a little) artistic.

**The challenge** is against yourself:

- Once you know the answer of the day find words using actual play that produce as many glyphs as possible from the answers below.
- Challenge yourself with arbitrary (not artistic) 6x5 patterns of three colors so long as no rows are impossible (for example GGGGGY is impossible to generate in play and GGGGGG must be last if it's used)

*Spring Has Sprung* is a relatively fun one.  The second turn can be challenging if there is only one vowel but otherwise it's easy and a good intro to this challenge.

[image]

*Marilyn* is very hard because turn 1 needs a suitable 5-letter anagram with no letter in its original position and turn 5 is even more constrained.

[image]

*Merry Christmas* is a present for you, making three challenges to begin.

[image]

Post more challenge glyphs in the Answers and challenge yourself to create as many as possible after solving each day's Wordle.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because without a definition of what would answer this question it turns into an ill-defined, open-ended puzzle (and open-ended puzzles are [off-topic as of May 2019](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles))

Comment: The idea of getting to row 4 of *Merry Christmas* and then not immediately solving the Wordle is making me itch all over...

Comment: As @PuzzlingFerret states, your question if off-topic for this site (see the guidance [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). This is a fun mechanic though, you could come up with your own [rebus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebus), limiting yourself to using glyphs in Wordle grids, and share that here.

Comment: Answers to this would change *literally every day*, and you even invite people to post new questions as part of their answers. This is a game, not a puzzle. Perhaps you'd like Reddit?

Comment: Instead of using today's wordle, I suggest to find any word that can satisfy all three simultaneously (if possible). If not possible, then the pictures need to be adjusted such that there exist at least one word (or exactly one word) that satisfy them. This question is very close to being on-topic, it'd be a shame to close it =)

Comment: @justhalf How would you pick an answer in that case?

Comment: If there is only one word that satisfies the three picture then it's a clear objective question I think? If there are two, then like many other questions, any answers are accepted (but should be not too many, perhaps 2-3 possible answers are acceptable). The question would be something like "Find a Wordle word for which you can make these pictures using guesses"

Comment: @justhalf that's definitely part of the challenge. The 'Challenge yourself with arbitrary (not artistic) 6x5 patterns of three colors so long as no rows are impossible' is not really in scope at all

Comment: @justhalf I think you've found a way to structure this in a more SE-friendly manner.   I'll work on it later (whether closed or not).

Comment: @justhalf if I take your suggestion and make this "find a Wordle answer word that can be the basis of producing these three glyphs in real play" I'd like the third glyph to be better, artistically.  I like the flowers and the girl.  The tree is a bit lame.  If you (or anyone) has any ideas go ahead and edit the closed question with your better glyph.  I'll restructure the question in the hope of reopening it, later.

Comment: But @justhalf asking the question your suggested way requires determining if there is a solution.   That's hard.   I'd love to find a well-formed puzzle based on this idea.

Comment: Yes, as the asker you need to know the answer first, or at least have reasonable evidence that it has an answer, and not too many answer. You can try in sandbox first maybe, to gather feedback from the community. One easy way, of course, is to come up with the word yourself, first, then form the pictures. And try solving it, if it has more solutions, try adding more pictures.

Comment: Yes yes hard, but writing good questions is hard

Answer (score 1):

Today's Wordle solution is

> LIGHT

You can draw *Spring has sprung* with the following tries:

> PIZZA
>  TILES
>  PIZZA
>  DIRTY
>  SINGS
>  LIGHT

You cannot draw a *Marylin*

> because of the constraints on row 5: there no word following the pattern LIG*H

I cannot create a *Merry Christmas* either

> because of the 4th and 6th rows, when we need a word with the pattern L*I*T or L*H*T.

But maybe someone with a better knowledge of English than me will find a way.

Comment: I'm downvoting this as an answer to a blatantly off-topic question

Comment: @PuzzlingFerret It makes absolutely no sense to downvote someone trying to help the OP regardless of topicness.

Comment: @RewanDemontay to me, it makes more sense than answering a blatantly off-topic question. Why close a question if people get answers regardless, when the close votes come in slowly. Also, as this question doesn't have a single definitive answer it's not 'helping' anybody in the way the site helps people normally.

Comment: I disagree with downvoting answers to off-topic questions.  But I agree that this one should be down-voted because it doesn't even answer the (off topic) question that was asked.    The question as posed is to come up with additional feasible challenges to be played against yourself.  (I understand now that is too open ended).  The question does not request solutions to a particular challenge.  If it did, there would be "daily answers", not the intent at all.